# How to change default properties in Maven Release Plugin for WSDL builds

Tags: eclipse, maven, wsdl, maven-release-plugin

I require the default properties of mvn release:prepare and mvn release:perform to be modified. The source code i'm trying to build has a WSDL files.

The JAR file that is generated is in non maven format and this was achieved 2 step build process, using this I'm able to generate the maven based WSDL compiled JAR file.

```
mvn exec:exec
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.stackoverflow.abc -DartifactId=xyz -Dversion=${BUILD_VERSION} -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=path-of-jar -DpomFile=path-of-pom.xml
```

This builds the JAR file with just MAINFEST.MF and with no pom.properties and pom.xml, What i'm trying to do is convert the JAR generated in non maven format to maven format.

When I try using release:prepare and release:perform, I'm unable to override the default properties as used in mvn install:install-file and there is no way to generate the JAR with pom properties

Is there a way i can override the mvn release plugin properties that would help me to build the JAR files?

Plugin used to build the WSDL:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>false</extensions>
            <version>1.2.1</version>

            <configuration>
            <executable>java</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-classpath</argument>
                    <classpath />
                    <argument>com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc</argument>
                    <argument>src/main/resources//Enterprise.wsdl</argument>
                    <argument>target/wsdl-${version}.jar</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
</plugin>
```

What i've tried using is:

```
mvn -s settings.xml -Dusername=${svn_user} -Dpassword=${svn_password} release:prepare exec:exec release:perform  -DgroupId=com.stackoverflow.abc -DartifactId=xyz -Dversion=${BUILD_VERSION} -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=${WORKSPACE}/target/wsdl-${BUILD_VERSION}.jar -DpomFile=${WORKSPACE}/pom.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below plugin is required to build the WSDL files, post that usual mvn clean install should do the job

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>false</extensions>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                  <id>custom-compile</id>
                  <phase>compile</phase>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
            <executable>java</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-classpath</argument>
                    <classpath />
                    <argument>com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc</argument>
                    <argument>src/main/resources/com/salesforce/wsdl/abc.wsdl</argument>
                    <!-- <argument>target/salesforce-wsdl-${project.version}.jar</argument> -->
                    <argument>target/salesforce-wsdl.jar</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```